# Activating a Conda environment in Ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I am trying to run a **list of tasks** (*here running airflow but it could be anything really*) that require to be executed in a existing Conda environment.

I would like to do these tasks:

```
- name: activate conda environment
 # does not work, just for the sake of understanding
 command: source activate my_conda_env

- name: initialize the database
  command: airflow initdb

- name: start the web server
  command: 'airflow webserver -p {{ airflow_webserver_port }}'

- name: start the scheduler
  command: airflow scheduler
```

Of course, this does not work as each task is independent and the `conda environment` activation in the first task is ignored by the following tasks.

I guess the issue would be the same if using a `python virtualenv` instead of `conda`.

How can I achieve each task being run in the Conda environment?

Answer (score 9):

Each of your commands will be executed in a different process.

`source` command, on the other hand, is used for reading the environment variables into the current process only (and its children), so it will apply only to the `activate conda environment` task.

What you can try to do is:

```
- name: initialize the database
  shell: source /full/path/to/conda/activate my_conda_env && airflow initdb
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- name: start the web server
  shell: 'source /full/path/to/conda/activate my_conda_env && airflow webserver -p {{ airflow_webserver_port }}'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- name: start the scheduler
  shell: source /full/path/to/conda/activate my_conda_env && airflow scheduler
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Before, check what's the full path to `activate` on the target machine with `which activate` (you need to do it before any environment is sourced). If Conda was installed in a user's space, you should use the same user for the Ansible connection.

Answer (score 2):

Was looking out for something similar. Found a neater solution than having multiple actions:

```
- name: Run commands in conda environment
  shell: source activate my_conda_env && airflow {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - initdb
    - webserver -p {{ airflow_webserver_port }}
    - scheduler
```